# How to change the query value using hook_views_query_alter?

Tags: 7, views

I am having a problem trying to change the query output on my view.

I am using this code:

```
function zed_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query){
  if ($view->name == 'questions_home' && $view->current_display == 'rates_related') {
    $or = db_or();
    dpr($query->where[1]['conditions'][2]['field']->condition());
  }
}
```

I am trying to alter the word `%california%`. The output is the following one.

```
DatabaseCondition Object
(
    [conditions:protected] => Array
        (
            [#conjunction] => OR
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [field] => node.title
                    [value] => %california%
                    [operator] => LIKE
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [field] => 
                    [value] => 
                    [operator] => IS NULL
                )

        )

    [arguments:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [changed:protected] => 1
    [queryPlaceholderIdentifier:protected] => 
)
```

How can I go about changing the value `%california%`?

Answer (score 3):

```
function zed_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'questions_home' && $view->current_display == 'rates_related') {
    foreach($query->where[1]['conditions'] as $idx => $condition) {
      if (!is_object($condition['field']) && $condition['field'] == 'node.title') {
        $query->where[1]['conditions'][$idx]['value'] = '%whateveryoulike%';
        // or you can unset this condition and write down a new one
        // unset($query->where[1]['conditions'][$idx]);
        // $query->add_where_expression('1', "$field LIKE %" . db_like("california") . "% OR field LIKE %" . db_like("somethingelse") . "%");
      }
    }
    dpr($query->where[1]['conditions']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Case of views query alter hooks we can use syntax similar below mentions

```
function hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  global $user;  
  if ($view->name == "Alerts") {    
     $query->where [0] ['conditions'] ['0'] ['value'] = '%' . $user->name . '%';
     $query->where [0] ['conditions'] ['0'] ['operator'] = "LIKE";
  }
}
```

Also you can change other $query->where positions data, This will impact in your query.

Answer (score 0):

To change query values in Filter criteria, you can use `hook_views_query_alter` in the following way:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_view') {

    // Assign my values.
    $value1 = 'This is my value for filter 1.';
    $value2 = 'This is my value for filter 2.';
    $value3 = 'This is my value for filter 3.';

    // Programatically update the filter criteria of a view.
    array_walk_recursive($query->where, create_function('&$v, $k', '$v = str_replace("_MY_TOKEN1_", "'.$value1.'", $v);'));
    array_walk_recursive($query->where, create_function('&$v, $k', '$v = str_replace("_MY_TOKEN2_", "'.$value2.'", $v);'));
    array_walk_recursive($query->where, create_function('&$v, $k', '$v = str_replace("_MY_TOKEN3_", "'.$value3.'", $v);'));
  }
}
```

Just change your value in your view to some custom token (`_MY_TOKEN1_`) and the function automatically find the right array key and it'll alter its value.

If you're using YQL View, use `hook_yql_views_query_query_alter()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($view->name == "SomeView_Name"){
       $query->where[1]['conditions'][0] = array('field'=>"node.title","value"=>'%california%',"operator"=>"LIKE");
}
```

I think this will help you.