# Views hook query alter, change the DatabaseCondition Object

Tags: views

I am trying to alter views filters with hook_views_query_alter like

```
function custom_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {      
     foreach($query->where[1]['conditions'] as $idx => $condition) {
      dpr($condition); 
     } 
}
```

And below is the output I get from DPR function

```
Array
(
    [field] => node.status
    [value] => 1
    [operator] => =
)
Array
(
    [field] => node.type
    [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => pricing
        )

    [operator] => in
)
Array
(
    [field] => DatabaseCondition Object
        (
            [conditions:protected] => Array
                (
                    [#conjunction] => AND
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [field] => field_data_field_zip_range.field_zip_range_from
                            [value] => 65000
                            [operator] => <=
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [field] => field_data_field_zip_range.field_zip_range_to
                            [value] => 65000
                            [operator] => >=
                        )

                )

            [arguments:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [changed:protected] => 1
            [queryPlaceholderIdentifier:protected] => 
        )

    [value] => 
    [operator] => 
)
```

So the first 2 filters are not a problem, you just edit the field and you set new values. Problem is the DatabaseCondition Object  with this conditions:protected part. I just don't have a clue how to change values there.

There was similar questions here [How to change the query value using hook_views_query_alter?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68216/views-hook-query-alter)  but it was not solved. It only solves problems for first 2 filters and doesn't do anything for DatabaseCondition Object.

Comment: `$conditions` is protected but [`conditions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21query.inc/function/DatabaseCondition%3A%3Aconditions/7) isn't...try `$conditions = &$condition->conditions();` and manipulate them directly

Comment: I just tried that in a way that I made

     foreach($query->where[1]['conditions'] as $idx => $condition) {
      $conditions = &$condition->conditions();
      dpr($conditions);
     }

And all I get is 500 Internal Server Error :(

Comment: @Clive - Thank You very much, this was exactly what I needed !

Comment: @MarkoBlazekovic HTTP 500 means "see server's error log for details". If you are still interested in this issue, post that details.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions may be altered by getting them by reference:

```
function custom_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
   $conditions = &$query->conditions();
   foreach($conditions as $idx => $condition) {
     if ($condition['field'] == 'node.type') {
       $conditions[$idx]['value'] = array("Some other type");
     }
   } 
}
```

Don't forget to modify the object/arrays by reference with the `&` character.

Comment: My page going blank using this code.

Answer (score 0):

solutions above didn't work for me since $query->conditions() results in php error.

but here's how how i solved something similar:

i have a view which has a list/text filter (multivalue) which has default values.  it is not exposed, but i change the values dynamically, depending on few $_GET values...

solution:

in hook_views_query_alter, $query->where[1]['conditions'][5]['field'] is a DatabaseCondition object--which i didn't manage to update, but i did override it's default value(s).

```
DatabaseCondition Object
(
[conditions:protected] => Array
    (
        [#conjunction] => OR
        [0] => Array
            (
                [field] => field_data_field_category_value_0.field_category_value
                [value] => apartment
                [operator] => =
            )
    )

[arguments:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[changed:protected] => 1
[queryPlaceholderIdentifier:protected] => 
)
```

what i did was to create a new DatabaseCondition and replace the old one:

```
<?php

// create db or
$db_or = db_or();
// add new condition
$db_or->condition('field_data_field_category_value_0.field_category_value', 'office', '=');
// assign new value
$query->where[1]['conditions'][5]['field'] = $db_or;
?>
```

also, you need to update $query->table_queue in order to match the new conditions.  in my case:

```
<?php

$query->table_queue['field_data_field_category_value_0']['join']->extra[0]['value'] = 'office';

?>
```

of course, table alias, field name, and index (0 in my example) should match your settings...